# When changing the index of an Elasticsearch alias via API, do write operations immediately point to the right index after the response?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-api

Let's say I got the alias `car-alias` pointing to `car-index-1`. I now want `car-alias` to point to `car-index-2`.

I therefore perform the following `POST` request to the [Aliases API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#indices-aliases):

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "index": "car-index-1",
        "alias": "car-alias"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "car-index-2",
        "alias": "car-alias"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I receive the following response:

```
{
   "acknowledged": true
}
```

Can I now immediately index data into the `car-alias` and it ends up in the `car-index-2`?

Or does the `"acknowledged": true` response not guarantee that write operations point to the right index immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the alias is changed [atomically](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/aliases.html#multiple-actions) and will point to `car-index-2` immediately when the call returns.

As stated in the documentation "...during the swap, the alias has no downtime and never points to both streams at the same time."

Comment: So the `acknowledged` flag does not mean that Elasticsearch just acknowledged the operation, but still maybe has some processing to do until is is completed?

Comment: No, it means it's safe and the writes will go to the new index.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Val's answer:

Since in your case, the alias only points to one index, the "next" index is automatically set as the write index.

From the docs regarding the `is_write_index` option of the add action:

> **is_write_index (Optional, Boolean)**
> If true, sets the write index or data stream for the alias.
>
> If an alias points to multiple indices or data streams and
> is_write_index isn’t set, the alias rejects write requests. **If an
> index alias points to one index and is_write_index isn’t set, the
> index automatically acts as the write index.** [...]
>
> Only the add action supports this parameter.

Comment: Note that this is only useful if the alias points to more than one indexes, the one to which the write requests should go, must be configured with `is_write_index: true`, but it doesn't seem to be the case here.